# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection:could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Have WAMPServe and yii-1.1.14 project. In `protected/config/main` have set up my `dbname='dev-romul'`, `host=localhost` and username and password.
When trying to load `index.php` of yii I get this message:

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

In `php.ini` I've included `php_pdo_mysql.dll`, `php_mysql.dll` and `php_mysql.dll`
but still receive this error message.

Also using phpMyAdmin I've checked  user privleges:

```
root    ::1  global  ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes
```

Hence remote connection is allowed.

Also tried all of these on remote server on openshift: still have this error message.

Someone please help to resolve this problem!

Comment: have you installed the dll?

Comment: sharing your `config/main.php` could really help you!

Comment: what about php_pdo_sqlite?

Comment: If you are sure about your database details, check config/main.php and make sure you have the connection as 'db', for example : 'db'=>array('connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev-romul' ...)